# nxt_lejos Tutorial vs. rosjava

Tags: nxt, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm unable to reconstruct the nxt_lejos [Getting Started Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_lejos_proxy/Tutorials/Getting%20Started) as "roslaunch proxy.launch" yields an error about missing rosjava_bootstrap run.py:

```
user@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/lejos/learning_nxt_lejos$ roslaunch proxy.launch
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/e479cc26-c074-11e1-8379-000c29dc495d/roslaunch-ubuntu-3394.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:42262/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosversion
 * /connection
 * /rosdistro
 * /nxt_robot
 * /brick_name

NODES
  /
    nxt_lejos_proxy (rosjava_bootstrap/run.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3408]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to e479cc26-c074-11e1-8379-000c29dc495d
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3421]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosjava_bootstrap/run.py]: Cannot locate node of type [run.py] in package [rosjava_bootstrap]
```

The file run.py is missing

which results from trying to perform run.py from rosjava_bootstrap as defined in proxy.launch:

```
<node pkg="rosjava_bootstrap" 
    type="run.py" 
    args="nxt_lejos_proxy org.lejos.ros.nodes.ROSProxy" 
    name="nxt_lejos_proxy" 
    output="screen">
```

As [current rosjava_bootstrap](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/#hg%2Frosjava_bootstrap%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fros) lacks such a file, this obviously fails.

How is one supposed to reconstruct the [Getting Started Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_lejos_proxy/Tutorials/Getting%20Started) with current rosjava_core?

Best regards,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37404/nxt_lejos-tutorial-vs.-rosjava/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial has been fixed. Please try it now.

---

Originally posted by [LawrieGriffiths](https://answers.ros.org/users/1997/lawriegriffiths/) with karma: 131 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0